# Data archival in jbpm 6.5

Tags: jboss, jbpm, jboss6.x

We are planning to use jbpm for financial transaction. And volume of these transaction is large. So time to time we need to archive data of jbpm tables. Is there any build in fuctionality for archiving? If not what should be the safest approach to archive data? We are using jbpm6.5. Please hepl

Comment: Hi Rupesh, I'm not an exper yet to jbpm but we are in the process of using it for managing huge volumes of transactions. As far as I known there is no build in functionality for archiving logs, only for cleanup, so probably you have to . If you check the db structure you can see that jbpm use different tables for active processes and audit (log) data.  LogCleanupCommand.java could be a reasonable starting point to develop what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using kie-workbench to perform process related operation then you can use REST API exposed by kie-workbench to clean DB tables. Use below REST endpoint to clear history records

[POST] /history/clear/